# Gap between basin waste and p Trap

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, renovation

First time poster – thanks for all replies.

I have just replaced a sink in my bathroom, but am finding it extremely frustrating replacing the P Trap under the sink for the following reason.

The original basin waste was very long, so I couldn't find one that was the same length as the original. I bought the longest one I could find, which now means that there is a tiny gap (about 20mm) between the basin waste and p trap that I cannot find any reasonable way to extending or adapting. Any adapter or extenders I've found are much to big for this gap.

All pipes are 40mm.

Does anyone know of an adapter that would be suitable in this situation? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you've created sort of an S-Trap, which could lead to the trap being siphoned empty. The gray pipe in the background shouldn't go up. The white elbow after the U-bend, should attach to the gray pipe where the lower elbow is. Which will mean you'll need an even longer tailpiece from the sink.

Comment: I agree with Tester you first should start with a longer tailpiece on the sink.

Answer (score -1):

You need to simplify your design and bring the trap down to the level of the outlet connection, like so:

[image]

It's a bit difficult to offer more detail with what I can't see in the photo. It may be that your outlet is so low that you can't achieve exactly that. Post a clear photo showing the entire thing (or just remove it all and show us the bare outlet).

Answer (score -1):

That's some tight quarters. I'd do it very differently and elbow off of the sink drain, etc. But for your circumstance, just get another one of those female to male top left adapters and pick up a cheap roll of Teflon Tape to wrap anything with threads at least 3-times. The Teflon Tape will make the threading easier and deeper as well as, of course, water-tight.